# TFS Build - Can I create a new branch and add the new mapping to my workspace dynamically?

Tags: visual-studio-2012, tfs, workflow, tfsbuild, branching-and-merging

As part of our CI, after each release we create a new branch and manually change the version number in our AssemblyInfo and Config files.  This is prone to human error and we have decided to automate this process.  So far I have a script that creates a new branch from our Main branch which I run before our build; the XAML has been modified with a number of activities that checks out all the AssemblyInfo and config files, updates the version numbers and checks the changes in.

What I want to do is to make this two stage process into a single process.  The idea I have at the moment is to add the "TF Branch" script as an invoke process at the beginning of my template before the "initialize Workspace" sequence; this will create the new branch (say branches\1.2.3.4).  After the branch has been created I then use a "TFWorkFold" activity placed just under "Create Workspace", in the TFWorkFold activity I add the new mapping - ( ServerPath = $\TeamProject\Branches\1.2.3.4 - LocalPath = SourcesDirectory) but when the process hits the "Get Workspace" activity none of the source files from the new branch are added to the Workspace.

When I run this on other builds the new mapping is successful, only if the branch has been created before the build is initialized.

Is there a step i'm missing? In my Create branch script i have a ping timer of 600secs to allow the branching enough time to complete before the new workspace mapping is added

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out,

After the new branch is created the build process needs to get the latest source files created.  In the Build definition I need to tell it to get the Latest Version, this is set in the "Process" section under "Advanced" then "Get Version" I set the value as "T" for "Get Latest".  Done :)